# Looking for a way to compress text (strings, not files) using Crystal Lang : having problem with the reverse operation

Tags: compression, crystal-lang

Compressing strings in RAM can be done by

```
require "compress/gzip"

compressed_string = String.build do |io|
  Compress::Gzip::Writer.open(io) do |gzip|
    gzip << "Compress me"
  end
end

p compressed_string
```

So far, so good, so I was trying to figure out how to carry out the reverse transform,
but the obvious mirror code doesn't seem to be the answer:

```
#########
# buggy #
#########

decompressed_string = String.build do |io|
  Compress::Gzip::Reader.open(io) do |gzip|
    gzip << compressed_string
  end
end

p decompressed_string
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct formulation was:

```
# Compress
compressed_string = String.build do |io|
  Compress::Gzip::Writer.open(io) do |gzip|
    gzip << "Compress me"
  end
end

p compressed_string


# Decompress
str = Compress::Gzip::Reader.open(IO::Memory.new (compressed_string)) do |gzip|
  gzip.gets_to_end
end

p str
```